# Index Out of Bounds When Using Viewpager and Calling same Fragment/Adapter on basis of Tab Location

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a view pager with two tabs Buy & Sell Respectively ,i am calling the same fragment using below code :

```
Product_fragment frag = new Product_fragment().newInstance(position);
return frag;
```

Now On Basis of My position i am populating my recylerview now the problem is when i click on any item in Tab 1 (i.e Buy Tab) i am getting index out of bond as my Tab 2's (i.e Sell Tab) array list is empty.

Is it possible to keep this two Tab's list different ,My Second Tab is overriding my first tab. I don't know what i am doing wrong.please guide me

Forgive my english

My FragmentStateAdapter

```
    public class MyOfferAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        int mNumOfTabs=2;
        Context context;
        boolean flag;

        private static int tabTitles[] = new int[] {
                R.string.sell,
                R.string.buy,
        };

        public MyOfferAdapter(boolean flag,FragmentManager fm, Context context)
        {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
            this.flag=flag;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                default:
                    Product_fragment frag = new Product_fragment().newInstance(flag,position);
                    return frag;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            //return "Tab " + (position + 1);
            return context.getResources().getString(tabTitles[position]);
        }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
public class Product_fragment extends Fragment {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "Product_Fragment";
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    Context context;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


    ArrayList<OfferModel> results = new ArrayList<OfferModel>();

    RelativeLayout progresslayout;

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private WebService api;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myoffer_fragment, container, false);
        final int a =getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE, 0);
        boolean flag=getArguments().getBoolean("flag");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "PAGE: " + a);
        intializeWeb();
        mRecyclerView  = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.chain_list);
        progresslayout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.progresslayout);
        recyleVIew();

        if(flag) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "TRUE ");
            searchyProduct(new StoreData(context).getUserid(), a);
        }else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FALSE ");
            searchyProduct("",a);
        }

        return view;
    }


    public Product_fragment newInstance(boolean flag,int someInt) {
        Product_fragment myFragment = new Product_fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, someInt);
        args.putBoolean("flag", flag);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }





    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }




    public void recyleVIew(){
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new ListSearchAdapter(context,results);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




        ((ListSearchAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new ListSearchAdapter.MyClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
                //openView(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class);
                OfferModel m = results.get(position);
                i.putExtra("offerDetails", m);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }

    public void searchyProduct(String userid,int type) {
        progresslayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Call<OfferPojo> call = api.searchMyOffer(userid, type);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OfferPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<OfferPojo> response) {
                OfferPojo contributors = response.body();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, contributors.getMessage());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, contributors.getCode());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, contributors.getStatus());
                results.clear();
                results.addAll(contributors.getData());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progresslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Throwable Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }





    public void intializeWeb() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
        httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        httpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Const.MY_ENDPOINT).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(httpClient.build()).build();
        api = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
03-01 16:16:00.350 10054-10054/com.justnear.justagro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.justnear.justagro, PID: 10054
                                                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 3
                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                           at com.justnear.justagro.fragment.Product_fragment$1.onItemClick(Product_fragment.java:137)
                                                                           at com.justnear.justagro.adapter.ListSearchAdapter$DataObjectHolder.onClick(ListSearchAdapter.java:70)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Can you put your FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: @Spirrow i did can you have a look

Comment: App is Crashing due to Tab 2 is overding tab1 adapter and causing Index Out of Bounds in Tab 1's RecylersView's on click . is it possible to create different instance of adapter for each fragment

Comment: Can you put your ListSearchAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Why is that code?

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

I think, it is more correctly:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitles.lengt;
}
```

And this construction can be improved:

```
switch (position) {
                default:
                    Product_fragment frag = new Product_fragment().newInstance(flag,position);
                    return frag;
            }
```

Simplify like this:

```
return new Product_fragment().newInstance(flag,position);
```

**UPDATE**

Try change this:

```
public Product_fragment newInstance(boolean flag,int someInt)
```

To this:

```
public static Product_fragment newInstance(boolean flag,int someInt)
```

And use it like this:

```
return Product_fragment.newInstance(flag,position);
```

Comment: App is Crashing due to Tab 2 is overding  tab1 adapter and causing Index Out of Bounds in Tab 1 RecylersView on click . There is no issue in adapter

Comment: can you help me out ?

Comment: Your problem is here: `OfferModel m = results.get(position);` The value of `position` is larger than `results.size(); - 1` Can you show me ListSearchAdapter class for more information.